# Windows 7 favorites not working in windows explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

For some reason I seem to have deleted all the favorites in the favorites menu in the file explorer. With favorites menu I mean this one:

[image: Screenshot of Windows Explorer with Favorites on the left]

Trying to add new links doesn't work and right clicking → Restore favorites doesn't work either. Trying to add a shortcut directly in the favorties folder within the user/favorites folder as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/16882/windows-7-32bit-not-adding-favorites-to-windows-explorer?rq=1) doesn't work either. Right now I'm actually clueless what to do.

Comment: [How can I restore the "Favorites" section of explorer after all entries have been deleted?](http://superuser.com/q/556065)

Comment: Have you rebooted since restoring the links?

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes I have, and I found some fixes online which stated I had to reset certain registery keys but that didn't work either. I also checked if the default location for the favorites folder had changed but it hasn't so its not trying to find the wrong folder or anything

Comment: If you create a new user, or login as another, are the favorite shortcuts there? If yes, your profile may be corrupt. If not, you may need to perform a repair install or full reinstall of Windows.

Comment: Still dont know exactly how I fixed it but I dragged in a new shortcut into the "Links" folder and suddenly the dropdown appeared in the favorites menu. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a extremely vague answer but I still don't know what fixed it.

If anyone has the same issue all I can tell you is to make sure you have 2 folders in your user folder. 1 folder named "Favorites" and 1 folder named "Links". For me my userfolder is C:\Users\Greg

If the two folders are correct they should show a special icon aswell. After that try creating a shortcut in either one of those or restoring the default links by right clicking favorites > restore default favorites. For me it seemed to work to drag in a location into the links folder.

Another thing you could look into is the registry, I found that allot of people seem to have issues with registry keys when it comes to this. [Have a look here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/104440-favorites-restore-default-favorite-links-navigation-pane.html)

[Here is a sample image of how the 2 folders should look](http://i.gyazo.com/5324eb21ca9dcef0ec85af9da18f724c.png)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

I copied the Links folder from another user profile to `%USERPROFILE%`

Then verified that the reg key below was set to `%USERPROFILE%\Links`

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\\{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}
```

Killed/Relaunched `explorer.exe` with Task Manager.

Voila